# Spring Boot WebFlux Kotlin R2DBC suspend pagination return type

Tags: spring, kotlin, spring-webflux, kotlin-coroutines, r2dbc

webflux r2dbc repository No example was found to return the page object.

Is there an appropriate way?

Let me know if you have a good example.

my service stack `spring-boot webflux`, `r2dbc`, `mysql`, `kotlin`

### repository

```kotlin
interface MemberContactableStatusRepository : ReactiveCrudRepository<MemberContactableStatusEntity, Long> {
        suspend fun findByUserId(userId: Long): MemberContactableStatusEntity?
        suspend fun findAllByUserId(userId: Long, pageable: Pageable): Page<MemberContactableStatusEntity>
    }
```

### error code

```sh
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'memberContactableHandler' defined in file [/Users/teddy/Projects/study/suspend/build/classes/kotlin/main/com/example/suspend/handler/MemberContactableHandler.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'memberContactableStatusService' defined in file [/Users/teddy/Projects/study/suspend/build/classes/kotlin/main/com/example/suspend/service/MemberContactableStatusService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'memberContactableStatusRepository' defined in com.example.suspend.domain.repository.MemberContactableStatusRepository defined in @EnableR2dbcRepositories declared on AuditingConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract java.lang.Object com.example.suspend.domain.repository.MemberContactableStatusRepository.findAllByUserId(long,org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable,kotlin.coroutines.Continuation)! Reason: Method has to use a either multi-item reactive wrapper return type or a wrapped Page/Slice type. Offending method: public abstract java.lang.Object com.example.suspend.domain.repository.MemberContactableStatusRepository.findAllByUserId(long,org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable,kotlin.coroutines.Continuation); nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method has to use a either multi-item reactive wrapper return type or a wrapped Page/Slice type. Offending method: public abstract java.lang.Object com.example.suspend.domain.repository.MemberContactableStatusRepository.findAllByUserId(long,org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable,kotlin.coroutines.Continuation)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:229) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1372) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:64) ~[spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) ~[spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332) ~[spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at com.example.suspend.SuspendApplicationKt.main(SuspendApplication.kt:13) ~[main/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'memberContactableStatusService' defined in file [/Users/teddy/Projects/study/suspend/build/classes/kotlin/main/com/example/suspend/service/MemberContactableStatusService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'memberContactableStatusRepository' defined in com.example.suspend.domain.repository.MemberContactableStatusRepository defined in @EnableR2dbcRepositories declared on AuditingConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract java.lang.Object com.example.suspend.domain.repository.MemberContactableStatusRepository.findAllByUserId(long,org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable,kotlin.coroutines.Continuation)! Reason: Method has to use a either multi-item reactive wrapper return type or a wrapped Page/Slice type. Offending method: public abstract java.lang.Object com.example.suspend.domain.repository.MemberContactableStatusRepository.findAllByUserId(long,org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable,kotlin.coroutines.Continuation); nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method has to use a either multi-item reactive wrapper return type or a wrapped Page/Slice type. Offending method: public abstract java.lang.Object com.example.suspend.domain.repository.MemberContactableStatusRepository.findAllByUserId(long,org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable,kotlin.coroutines.Continuation)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:229) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1372) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'memberContactableStatusRepository' defined in com.example.suspend.domain.repository.MemberContactableStatusRepository defined in @EnableR2dbcRepositories declared on AuditingConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract java.lang.Object com.example.suspend.domain.repository.MemberContactableStatusRepository.findAllByUserId(long,org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable,kotlin.coroutines.Continuation)! Reason: Method has to use a either multi-item reactive wrapper return type or a wrapped Page/Slice type. Offending method: public abstract java.lang.Object com.example.suspend.domain.repository.MemberContactableStatusRepository.findAllByUserId(long,org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable,kotlin.coroutines.Continuation); nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method has to use a either multi-item reactive wrapper return type or a wrapped Page/Slice type. Offending method: public abstract java.lang.Object com.example.suspend.domain.repository.MemberContactableStatusRepository.findAllByUserId(long,org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable,kotlin.coroutines.Continuation)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    ... 38 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract java.lang.Object com.example.suspend.domain.repository.MemberContactableStatusRepository.findAllByUserId(long,org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable,kotlin.coroutines.Continuation)! Reason: Method has to use a either multi-item reactive wrapper return type or a wrapped Page/Slice type. Offending method: public abstract java.lang.Object com.example.suspend.domain.repository.MemberContactableStatusRepository.findAllByUserId(long,org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable,kotlin.coroutines.Continuation); nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method has to use a either multi-item reactive wrapper return type or a wrapped Page/Slice type. Offending method: public abstract java.lang.Object com.example.suspend.domain.repository.MemberContactableStatusRepository.findAllByUserId(long,org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable,kotlin.coroutines.Continuation)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException.create(QueryCreationException.java:101) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:106) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$mapMethodsToQuery$1(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:94) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.forEachRemaining(Collections.java:1054) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.mapMethodsToQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$new$0(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:86) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:265) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:86) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:360) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:323) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:230) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:114) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:329) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.r2dbc.repository.support.R2dbcRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(R2dbcRepositoryFactoryBean.java:167) ~[spring-data-r2dbc-1.3.5.jar:1.3.5]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    ... 49 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method has to use a either multi-item reactive wrapper return type or a wrapped Page/Slice type. Offending method: public abstract java.lang.Object com.example.suspend.domain.repository.MemberContactableStatusRepository.findAllByUserId(long,org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable,kotlin.coroutines.Continuation)
    at org.springframework.data.r2dbc.repository.query.R2dbcQueryMethod.<init>(R2dbcQueryMethod.java:105) ~[spring-data-r2dbc-1.3.5.jar:1.3.5]
    at org.springframework.data.r2dbc.repository.support.R2dbcRepositoryFactory$R2dbcQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(R2dbcRepositoryFactory.java:186) ~[spring-data-r2dbc-1.3.5.jar:1.3.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:102) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    ... 71 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

r2dbc does not support page/slice type, so you can do this:

```kotlin
fun findAllByUserId(userId: Long, pageable: Pageable): Flow<MemberContactableStatusEntity>
```

And if you need other data(such as totalPage), you need to query again

```kotlin
suspend fun countByUserId(userId: Long, pageable: Pageable): Long
```

Comment: is it stillt true in 2023?

Comment: Note that the pageable should be removed from the count query.